# Как динамически обратиться к свойству объекта?

Tags: php, json

Есть такой код, $json это массив данных, ответ сервера, может быть разным, поэтому требуется динамически сформировать к чему обращаться.

Почитал данный раздел http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php и не могу обратиться к нулевому элементу.

```
$num_hist = count($json->list[0]->Item->HistoryItemList);
```

Как вообще сохранить данную строку `list[0]->Item->HistoryItemList` чтобы потом получать данные сформировав `$json->...`?

То есть требуется вроде такого массива из которого потом собрать строку для получения данных из $json

```
$arr = [
        'list[0]',
        'Item',
        'HistoryItemList',
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные-переменные в данном случае не помогут. Можно воспользоваться [eval()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php) (собрать путь к свойству в строку кода и выполнить), но я бы предложил другой вариант:

Второй аргумент функции [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) позволяет представить JSON-объекты как ассоциативные массивы. Это позволит использовать единую нотацию (через квадратные скобки) для любых элементов.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// [
//     'list' => [
//         0 => [
//             'Item' => [
//                 'HistoryItemList' => 123
//             ]
//         ]
//     ]
// ];
```

Тогда можно последовательно пройтись по элементам пути и извлечь нужное значение:

```
$path = ['list', 0, 'Item', 'HistoryItemList'];
$next = $data;

foreach ($path as $element) {
    $next = $next[$element];
}

echo $next; // 123
```

Comment: в яблочко! суперсенкс.